# Using comp ling software: on topic or not?

Tags: discussion, off-topic-questions, computational-linguistics

**[Semantically Analyse words in a text document using wordnet](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/8441/2555)**

I think that this kind of question should be considered off topic and migrated to stack exchange. Questions about how to use a particular comp ling software tool are not really about linguistics. Comp ling questions should be about the theory... ones like [this one](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2654/2555) seem decent. Actually looking at the tag a lot of them look like poor questions... but lets stick to this question for now.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if someone asks how to use Praat (for example) for a particular task, that would be on topic. But if somebody asks for a question that requires coding knowledge (mostly or only) than yes, it might be better to migrate it. Not because it's a bad question but because it's more likely to find experts on another site than here.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not seem off-topic to me, though I find it quite lacking in effort. I don't think the question will elicit quality answers whether it is migrated or not.

In general, though, I wouldn't think questions that focus on particular software tools should be considered off-topic here. Taking this question as an example, WordNet, though a software tool, has been fertile ground for quite a lot of linguistic R&D. And there *are* tools that linguists and computational linguists know better than software developers at large do. Praat is one example that Alennano mentioned, and then we have Festival, Mary, IMSKPE, etc.

---

Apparently, he had already [asked this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371825/semantically-analyse-words-in-a-text-document-using-wordnet), and he was directed to Ling.SE.